# Constraint optimization of the linear H4 and H6 chain with gaussian

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I want to optimize the linear hydrogen chain ($d_{\infty h}$, equal bond lengths) with `gaussian 16`.

Using `z-matrix`

```
# opt=z-matrix hf/sto-3g


H6 chain

0 1
 H              
 H  1  r1
 H  2  r1  1  a1
 H  3  r1  2  a1  1  d1
 H  4  r1  3  a1  2  d1
 H  5  r1  4  a1  3  d1
Variables:
r1=0.9
Constants:
a1=180.0
d1=0.0
```

is not possible, since angles of 0° and 180° are not allowed.

```
 Error on Z-matrix line number      3:  angle Alpha is outside the valid range of 0 to 180.
 Error on Z-matrix line number      4:  angle Alpha is outside the valid range of 0 to 180.
 Error on Z-matrix line number      5:  angle Alpha is outside the valid range of 0 to 180.
 Error on Z-matrix line number      6:  angle Alpha is outside the valid range of 0 to 180.
 Conversion from Z-matrix to cartesian coordinates failed:
```

Using generalized internal coordinate optimization (`GIC`) module

```
#p hf/sto-3g
opt geom(AddGIC)

H4 chain

0 1
 H              
 H  1  r1
 H  2  r1  1  a1
 H  3  r1  2  a1  1  d1
Variables:
r1=0.9
Constants:
a1=180.0
d1=0.0

R12(active)=R(1,2)
R23(active)=R(2,3)
R34(active)=R(3,4)
R23(modify)=R12
R34(modify)=R12

LinBend1H1H2H3(freeze)=L(1,2,3,0,-1)
LinBend2H1H2H3(freeze)=L(1,2,3,0,-2)
LinBend1H2H2H4(freeze)=L(2,3,4,0,-1)
LinBend2H2H3H4(freeze)=L(2,3,4,0,-2)
```

does not work either.

```
 ***** Axes restored to original set *****
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 Center     Atomic                   Forces (Hartrees/Bohr)
 Number     Number              X              Y              Z
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        1          -0.000000000    0.000000000    0.093021603
      2        1           0.000000000   -0.000000000   -0.205327093
      3        1           0.000000000    0.000000000    0.205327093
      4        1          -0.000000000   -0.000000000   -0.093021603
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 Cartesian Forces:  Max     0.205327093 RMS     0.092025570
 Leave Link  716 at Fri Apr 24 15:09:36 2020, MaxMem=  1342177280 cpu:               0.4 elap:               0.1
 (Enter /usr/local_rwth/sw/gaussian/LINUX_emt64/g16.c01_bin_avx2/l103.exe)

 GradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGrad
 Berny optimization.
 NTrRot=    -1 NTRed=     6 NAtoms=     4 NSkip=    -1 IsLin=T
 Problem with coordinate system.
```

How can this be done?